# referencing table in parent query in a subquery with SUM and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

My query looks something like this :

```
SELECT tablea.field,
(
 SELECT sum(count) FROM
 (
      SELECT count(distinct(subtable.regdate)) as count
      FROM subtable
      where subtable.regid = tableb.regid
      GROUP BY subtable.userid

 ) as a

) as thesum
FROM tablea 
LEFT JOIN tableb on tableb.id = tablea.tableaid
GROUP BY tablea.field2
```

the problem is that in my sub query the referenced table "tableb" is unknown so i get the error : "Unknown column 'tableb.regid' in 'where clause' "

How can i solve this?

thx !

Comment: Cant you substitute tableb.regid in your sub for  (select regid from tableb) as tablebregid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the subquery to the `from` clause:

```
SELECT tablea.field, thesum
FROM tablea left join
     tableb
     on tableb.id = tablea.tableaid left join
     (select st.regid, sum(count) as thesum
      from (SELECT st.regid, st.userid, count(distinct(st.regdate)) as count
            FROM subtable st
            GROUP BY st.regid, st.userid
           ) st
      group by st.regid
     ) st
     on st.regid = tableb.regid
GROUP BY tablea.field2;
```

However, your original query should work.  I suspect that there is a typo in the name.  Or perhaps `tableb` is actually in a subquery (in which case it would be out of scope) or it has an alias an you are using the base table name.